# ECharts: Is it possible to pause the animation in a bar race charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I am building a bar race chart using this ECharts example: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-race-country

I'd like to add buttons for pause/play and reset, but I am not sure if pausing animation is possible.

For reset, I should be able to figure out how to re-trigger loading of the chart, so I'm not too worried about that one.

Is it possible to pause and resume animation in ECharts?

Comment: Don't have any experience with ECharts, but maybe this can help: https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.timeline.timelineChange

Comment: I don't think there is a documented way to pause an animation that is in progress and I'm not sure it's worth the bother. Why not just pause with a small delay allowing the current animation to complete?